# Example of a ring with infinitely many zero divisors and finitely many invertible elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am preparing to my abstract algebra exam and I try to find an example of a ring with **infinitely many zero divisors and finitely many invertible elements**  (rather simple if possible).
Does it even exist?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 16):

$\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.  There are only $(-1,1),(-1,-1),(1,1),(1,-1)$ as invertible elements but infinitely many zero divisors $(a,0)$ for every $a$.

Answer (score 3):

The power set of $\: \{\hspace{-0.02 in}0,\hspace{-0.05 in}1\hspace{-0.02 in},\hspace{-0.04 in}2,\hspace{-0.04 in}3,...\hspace{-0.04 in}\} \:$ [is an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring#Examples) of such a ring.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\mathbb{Z}\times R$ for $R$ any nontrivial ring with only finitely many invertible elements.

Comment: Hey Noah good to see your around.  How goes the diss?